# Deploying a react app @ username.github.io

Tags: reactjs, github, github-pages

I am  trying to deploy a react app at `username.gihub.io`

There are 2 main issues

1. Whenever I try to build an application in react with gh-pages and
   deploy it goes to the branch gh-pages.
2. Gihub always serves  from the branch master, if the repo name is
   `username.github.io` (cannot be changed )

Has anyone deployed a react app in this url. If so, tell me how did you do it?

(Other than drag and drop build folder to master )

Image : [image]

Comment: If you deploy using `gh-pages` it'll create a new branch and from there it serves to the web page. `gh-pages` doesn't serve from master. If you want to serve from master then you'll have to upload your build to master and set the branch manually. If you want to change the web address then you need to buy your own domain, but by default your hosted web address will be `username.github.io/project-name`.

Comment: please refer the uploaded image.

Comment: Now, I have deleted the files in gh-pages, so you will not find any files but it was there before.

Comment: maybe this link will solve your issue. > https://pages.github.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to deploy using GitHub now is by the new deploy from docs folder found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/) at the end of the page.

You should be able to tweak your app to run build into the docs folder, way less headache than trying to get regular github-pages working imo.

For fast sanity checking you can also drag your app into /docs

Answer (score 0):

First make a `develop` branch, pull all code from `master`, then empty the `master` branch project. Work on the `develop` branch with the install dependencies, test with local then run:

```
npm run build
npm run deploy
```

After development is complete, `checkout` to `master` branch and run:

```
pull origin gh-pages branch
git add .
git commit -m "your massage" 
git push origin master
```

Now you can check your `username.github.io`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same doubt, I'm following the steps from https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/
to build and deploy, so I just went to my repo > settings > GH Pages > Serve from gh-pages branch and it worked without further config.